# using openCV with jupyter nobook resets the execution

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to load the dogs vs cats dataset,and using openCV to manipulate the image so I can use a ML algorithm on the data.

almost every thing works except one thing which is the background removal tool in openCV.
for some reason it just reset the execution order (the cell after I try this becomes cell [1]).

this is the problematic cell

```
img = cv.imread('data/Cats and dogs/train/cat.16.jpg')
print(img.shape)

img = cv.BackgroundSubtractorKNN().apply(img)
```

after this I'm running this:

`cv.imshow(img)`

and it's just appearing as cell [1] and failing because cv is not imported.

any idea why this occurs?

Answer (score 0):

These are some things that you might consider:

1. Have you imported OpenCV correctly? ex) import cv2 as cv
2. Have you tried defining the KNN back-sub algorithm as a variable likewise?

```
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('data/Cats and dogs/train/cat.16.jpg')
print(img.shape)

backSub = cv.createBackgroundSubtractorKNN()
fgMask = backSub.apply(frame)

cv.imshow(fgMask)
```

If problem reoccurs, try installing OpenCV again